# Fetch records using join with has_many :through relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a `Hotel` model and `HotelAmenity` model and `Amenity` model which are related by `has_many :through` like this:

```
class Hotel < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :hotel_amenities, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :amenities, through: :hotel_amenities
end

class Amenity < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :hotel_amenities, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :hotels, through: :hotel_amenities
end


class HotelAmenity < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :amenity
  belongs_to :hotel
end
```

Now I have `hotel_id` in my action and I want to fetch all the hotels who have amenities `[1,2,3]` this is the `array` of `amenity_id`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good Question !!
Don't worry you can solve out this problem using `join` on the `Hotel Model` as : 
First of all you will find the hotel by `hotel_id`

```
@hotel= Hotel.find_by_id(params[:user_id))
```

Now you can find the hotels with `amenity_array` `[1,2,3]`

```
 @hotels = @hotels.joins(:hotel_amenities).where(hotel_amenities: { amenity_id: [1,2,3] }) // this can returns a hotel two or more time


@hotels = @hotels.joins(:hotel_amenities).where(hotel_amenities: { amenity_id: [1,2,3] }).uniq // this will return all hotels without redundant records
```

Hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
arr= [1,2,3] 
Hotel.joins(:hotel_amenities).select("hotel_amenities.*,hotels.*").where("hotel_amenities.amenity_id= ?",arr)
```